# Get button that launched the flyout

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app

I have a GridView and in that I have a button with a flyout. I have two methods on the MenuFlyoutItems in which I need to know the buttons properties that invoked the flyout. Is there a way to do it?

My code:

```
<Button Content="{x:Bind Text}" Name="{x:Bind Id}">
         <Button.Flyout>
              <MenuFlyout Placement="Bottom">
                      <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Remove" Click="Remove_Click" />
                      <MenuFlyoutSeparator/>
                      <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Select" Click="Select_Click"/>
              </MenuFlyout>
        </Button.Flyout>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ContainerFromItem`  return `GridViewItem`. You can get button element using VisualTreeHelper

```
   private void Remove_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MenuFlyoutItem mfi = (MenuFlyoutItem)sender;
        var datacontext = mfi.DataContext;
        GridViewItem item = grd.ContainerFromItem(datacontext) as GridViewItem ;
        Button button = FindElementInVisualTree<Button>(item);
    }
 private T FindElementInVisualTree<T>(DependencyObject parentElement) where T : DependencyObject
        {
            var count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parentElement);
            if (count == 0) return null;

            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parentElement, i);
                if (child != null && child is T)
                    return (T)child;
                else
                {
                    var result = FindElementInVisualTree<T>(child);
                    if (result != null)
                        return result;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I can't try to be sure, but you can try the way like this:

```
        private void Remove_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MenuFlyoutItem mfi = (MenuFlyoutItem)sender;
        var datacontext = mfi.DataContext;
        Button item = grd.ContainerFromItem(datacontext) as Button;
    }
```

Where grd is name of your GridView

Comment: Dont cast it to button. I hope ContainerFromItem returns GridViewItem if im not wrong. Check and let me know

Comment: Yes, probably. Unfortunately I can't check it now. Hope has show you right direction.

Comment: It doesn't, the cast is needed otherwise it will produce an error.